# Windows Phone 7, create a serializable class

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, serializable

how can i make my custom class serializable and "savable" into IsolatedStorageSettings as value in a key-value pair? I tried with [DataContract] on top of class but VisualStudio says me that it can't be found!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Add Reference dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to add reference to assembly mentioned by qianfg (`System.Runtime.Serialization`).

Then you can add `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` line to your file.

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to the assembly System.Runtime.Serialization to your code.

Comment: Do you mean "using System.Runtime.Serialization;" ? Still not working!